# Greasemonkey script testfor url & add parameter

Tags: youtube, greasemonkey, userscripts

I want to check for site youtube.com and if it is a video site (includes `watch?v=`) then add `&rel=0` to the url. Pseudocode:

```
if url = youtube.com/watch?v=* |then newurl = url + &rel=0
```

More examples:

- youtube.com -> youtube.com
- youtube.com/feed/subscriptions -> youtube.com/feed/subscriptions
- youtube.com/watch?v=ikIXmUUumjg -> youtube.com/watch?v=ikIXmUUumjg&rel=0
- youtube.com/watch?v=ikIXmUUumjg&t=0 -> youtube.com/watch?v=ikIXmUUumjg&t=0s&rel=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to use modern javascript to replace URL without redirecting. Second trick is to know that `window.location` contains parsed URL divided in sections (hostname, path, query arguments...).

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        window rel youtube
// @namespace   util
// @match       *://www.youtube.com/*
// @version     1
// @grant       none
// ==/UserScript==
const watchRegex = /watch\?v=/i
if(window.location.href.indexOf("watch?v=")!=-1 && window.location.search.indexOf("rel=0")==-1) {
    console.log("changing url");
    var baseURL = window.location.origin + window.location.pathname+window.location.search+"&rel=0"+window.location.hash;
    window.history.pushState({"pageTitle":document.title},"", baseURL);
}
else {
    console.log("No change in url");
}
```

Comment: Can't try it out rn. Synergy install is making my pc to bluescreen bootloop

Comment: @RasmusA You don't need to let me know about that. Test it when you have time and a working PC and then comment if there was a problem or accept the answer if it worked.

Comment: it doesn't work and you know the thing youtube did recently if you have adblock, then play 1 min ad or so, it triggerd that

Comment: fixed it, const watchRegex = /watch\?v=/i; needed the last semicolon for some reason, tampermonkey even errored it

Comment: @rasmusa I will edit it as soon as I get to PC. Thanks for reporting the error. It worked for me though, semicolons are not always mandatory in JS.